# batch to move columns in a CSV file

Tags: batch-file, csv

I have a CSV file that is created automatically that contains multiple columns. One of these columns is called "sn". I need to ensure that sn is never the first column in the CSV file. Unfortunately I cannot edit the program creating the program.

Therefore in a batch file I would like to:

- open CSV
- check where the sn column is
- if it is in column 1 then move it to another column (column 2 is fine)
- save changes

Is this possible in a batch file?

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system, what programming language, any constraints? What did you try?

Comment: Tomorrow you will ask to write database server using batch files. Why do not use any real programming language to do that?

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes, it is possible". But quite some effort. With ruby and the csv module it is trivial. Just google "ruby csv tutorial" and you can write a script for this task in 30 mins.

Comment: Hi - OK I was looking for feasibility feedback - I will look for a better solution! Thanks for replying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 SET "choosing="
 SET "movecol="
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=," %%a IN (q20995223.txt) DO (
  IF NOT DEFINED choosing (
   IF "%%a"=="sn" SET movecol=Y
   SET choosing=N
  )
  IF DEFINED movecol (ECHO(%%b,%%a) ELSE (ECHO(%%a,%%b)
 )
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

If the first column on the first line contains `sn`, then the remaining columns are moved left one and the `sn` column moved to last. Otherwise the file is simply reproduced to `newfile.txt`

`q20995223.txt` was my test file. Renaming them to suit is your task.